# I am having trouble with a Js code for a parallax effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I am trying to make a parallax effect where the landing page image stays still then the body paragraph below comes up and over the image. I have it where it works but the image still moves and then a white space shows up on the top.

js:

```
function scrollFooter(scrollY, heightFooter)
{
console.log(scrollY);
console.log(heightFooter);

if(scrollY >= heightFooter)
{
    $('footer').css({
        'bottom' : '0px'
    });
}
else
{
    $('footer').css({
        'bottom' : '-' + heightFooter + 'px'
    });
}
}

$(window).load(function(){
var windowHeight        = $(window).height(),
    footerHeight        = $('footer').height(),
    heightDocument      = (windowHeight) + ($('').height()) + ($('footer').height()) - 20;


$('#scroll-animate, #scroll-animate-main').css({
    'height' :  heightDocument + 'px'
});
```

Thanks again for any help!

```
$('header').css({
    'height' : windowHeight + 'px',
    'line-height' : windowHeight + 'px'
});


scrollFooter(window.scrollY, footerHeight);

window.onscroll = function(){
    var scroll = window.scrollY;

    $('#scroll-animate-main').css({
        'top' : '-' + scroll + 'px'
    });

    $('header').css({
        'background-position-y' : 50 - (scroll * 400 / heightDocument) + '%'
    });

    scrollFooter(scroll, footerHeight);
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to use JQuery to do parallax effect on a HTML page. Simple CSS can be satsify your need.

```
.parallaxEffect {
background-color: //color you wanted or use background-image: url(your link);
height: //your height
background-repeat: no-repeat;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
position: fixed; //fixed the pic do not change to relative otherwise the effect will lost
width: 100%;}

.parallaxTitle { //remove if you don't need to put title inside your image
font-size: 80px;
color: #eee;
margin-top: 10%;
text-align: center;}     

.yourContent {
max-width: 100%;
position: relative;
top: 400px;
padding: 0px;
font-size: 20px;
background-color: #fff;}
```

Your only need to apply the below to your website than it will be sort, you can do some advance modification in order to fulfill your requirement.